# Logica de emprestimo em uma biblieteca

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actions

Estou querendo fazer uma logica de um emprestimo de livro de uma biblioteca,

Fiz um scaffold para livro um para usuario e outro para emprestimo.

Na lista de livros em cada livro tem um botao emprestar quando clico ele leva o id e o nome do livro para os emprestimos, em emprestimo guardara o id o nome do livro e irei setar um usuario para esse emprestimo.

O problema que to achando e fazer com que quando eu emprestar um livro ele fique indisponivel para ser emprestado e para fazer a devolução desse livro

OBS: Estou trabalhando com ruby a apenas dois meses em um estagio, nunca usei a linguagem antes.

Comment: você conseguiu resolver essa questão?

Comment: Sim!!!!! consegui, coloquei nos livros um atributo situação do tipo string e cada vez que eu clicar no botão emprestar dou um update na situação do livro para em uso e ele não aparecera na tabela enquanto estiver em uso e quando for devolvido vai fazer um outro update na situação para disponivel